# Dynamic page implementation in react not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to switch two different components onto a single page. I have a switch statement but I can't figure out how to switch the components to display onto the pages. Any help would be appreciated.

````
**Code below**<br/>
```type PageThreeTypes = 
  | ''
  | 'preview'
  | 'receipt'
  | 'submit'```

```export class Store {
  pageThreeType: PageThreeTypes = ''

 onSetPageThreeType = (data: PageThreeTypes) => {
    this.pageThreeType = data
  }

}```

**Below is the page I am doing the switching**<br/>
```const PageSwitch = observer(() => {

    const { Store } = useStore()
    const [screen, setScreen] = useState<any>(null)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      autorun(() => {
        switch (Store.pageThreeType) {
          case 'preview':
            return(<><PageThreePreview/></>)
            break
  
            case 'receipt':
                return(<><PageThreeReceipt/></>)
                break

            case 'submit':
                return(<><PageThreePreview/></>)
                break    
        }
      })
    }, [Store])

  return (
    <div >
      
    </div>
  )
})

export default PageThree```
<br/>
Any help would be appreciated on how to switch the pages. Thanks.
````

Comment: just move that switch statement out of useEffect

Comment: Alright. And how would I get the different pages to be rendered?